graalvm swing program in linux cannot switch to Chinese input methods in the JTextField component
# my graalvm version 
export GRAALVM_HOME=/home/mxh/software/graalvm-jdk-21.0.3+7.1
export JAVA_HOME=/home/mxh/software/graalvm-jdk-21.0.3+7.1
export PATH=$JAVA_HOME/bin:$PATH
export GRAALVM_HOME
# my os version
Operating System: UOS Desktop 20 Professional
Kernel: Linux 6.1.32-amd64-desktop-hwe
Architecture: x86-64


run in java -jar

java -agentlib:native-image-agent=config-output-dir=config -Djdk.gtk.version=2 -jar lessions.jar

There is no problem running in Java -jar lessions.jar

run in native-image

native-image --no-fallback -H:+AddAllCharsets -H:ConfigurationFileDirectories=config --enable-url-protocols=https,http -Djava.awt.headless=false  --allow-incomplete-classpath -J-Xmx16G -Djdk.gtk.version=2 -jar lessions.jar

./lessions
cannot switch input method to non English state
The program cannot recognize other input methods.
I have added - Djdk. gtk. version=2 to the native-image parameter, but it seems to have no effect.
I hope to input Chinese in the swing program of Graalvm Linux Native.
graal_issues

Looks swing is not supported yet by graalvm for UI you can try gluon
